# UItextView not show long text

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have UITextView in my view and I set a text with 10000 character to it but is show only white space scroll. but its ok with short text (for example 1000 character).
how could I fix this?

Comment: I have this problem with long text too.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix it by replacing `UITextView` with `UILabel` and `UIScrollView`